# Error with ODBC MS ACCESS - Oracle 9i

Tags: oracle, ms-access, odbc

I want connect MS Access with Oracle 9i. In Oracle I have a few table and in MS Access I want make a new reccords.

Now I have a problem with ODBC I got error:

```
"[Microsoft][ODBC driver for oracle][Oracle]ORA-12514: TNS: nasłuchowi nie udało się rozstrzygnąć SERVICE_NAME podanego w deskryptorze połączenia (#12514)..........."
```

In configuraton file DSN I have only:

```
[ODBC]
DRIVER=Microsoft ODBC for Oracle
```

and after that I must write login, password and server (I writing example data 192.168.1.1)

my TNSNAMES.ORA

```
BAZA_AAA =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxx)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = BAZA_AAA))
)
```

Others program example SQL Server , TOAD, windows console writing my database but not access

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Instead of IP of server try to use TSN name: `BAZA_AAA`.

Also this was the 1st time I used MS driver for Oracle. I have always used drivers by Oracle. Do you have them installed? Have you tried them? They have 'TNS Service Name' field and 'Test Connection' button :-)